# MySQL eliminating rows after left join

Tags: mysql

I found a weird way of how mysql does something. Someone please explain why it happens.
I select all the columns from table A, and left join from table B with a certain condition, that may or may not be met for each table A row.
 Now after the joins, in the WHERE statement, I want to completely leave out rows (not the join part, but whole rows) that have a table B's column categoryId of value 14 IF the there are table B results (if there aren't, I do want the row to be kept).
 So in WHERE I do `WHERE tableB.categoryId != 14`. There are no results (when there are supposed to be). For curiosity, I tried to rewrite the operator to =, so `WHERE tableB.categoryId = 14`, and the result was that the results I wanted I didn't get, a and the results I didn't want I did get.
I don't understand this, this is weird.
Shouldn't the not equals thing have worked?
I also tried !(`tableB.categoryId = 14`), but that also yielded no results. At the end, I tried `WHERE IF(tableB.categoryId = 14, 0, 1)`, and that did work for some reason. Why did that work and why didn't the not equals and negating operators work?

Comment: [Paragraphs are your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll pay attention next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `WHERE tableB.categoryId IS NULL OR tableB.categoryId != 14`

Comment: Comparing a number (any) to NULL is always tricky, so when you need to address that possibility, you need to address NULL values explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has nothing to do with left join.

For debugging you should try a simpler query without the left join.
Just `SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE categoryId = 14`

Also check the type the the categoryId, the problem may be implicit conversions from int to string that are not working in all contexts, so they are better made explicit.